# Prove that there is a unique real number $c$ such that there is a unique real number $x$ such that $x^2 + 3x + c = 0$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I encountered the above question in the book 'How to Prove It' by Velleman in Chapter 3.6, Exercise 13(a). I have trouble formulating the logical form for this particular example. From the definition, I was able to get the following (incomplete) form:

$$
\exists! c \ \exists! x \ (x^2 + 3x + c = 0) \\
\exists c \ [\exists! x \ \left(x^2 + 3x + c = 0 \ \wedge \ \forall y \ (x^2 + 3x + y = 0 \implies y = c)\right)] 
$$

How would I further simplify the above form, especially with regards to the part for $\exists! x$? I proceeded to compute an expression for $c$ using the quadratic formula to get $c = \frac{9 - (2x+3)^2}{4}$, but it didn't take me long to realise this was likely to be erroneous since the expression implicitly implies an arbitrary $x$ rather than a unique solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x=0, c=0$ and $x=1,c=-4$ are both solutions. so there is no unique solution

Comment: @Babydesta OP needs to show that the equation $x^2+3x+c=0$ has unique solution for a unique $c$.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question

Comment: What about $c=(3/2)^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked two questions, one concerning logic and the other concerning quadratic equations.

For your first question, the whole sentence after $\exists!c$ needs to be "duplicated", i.e.

$$\exists c\  ((\exists! x \ (x^2 + 3x + c = 0))\land \forall d\ ((\exists! x \ (x^2 + 3x + d = 0))\implies d=c))$$

For your second question, use the discriminant $\Delta = b^2-4ac$.

Recall that the discriminant is zero if and only if there is a unique solution to $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Comment: I think you mean "discriminant", not "determinant."

Comment: Sorry, I have been teaching matrices and quadratic equations simultaneously.

Comment: Got it. I will try again with the new information provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

Need to find $c$ s.t. the equation has a double root.

Complete the square:

$y=(x-3/2)^2-9/4+c;$

Double root: $-9/4+c=0;$

$c=9/4.$